# SQL Show duplicate records only once in a result set

Tags: sql

Is it possible in SQL to show duplicate records in a result only once.

*So instead of this*

```
         my@email.com | Some Unique Data | Unique Data

         my@email.com | Some Unique Data | Unique Data

         my@email.com | Some Unique Data | Unique Data

         my@email.com | Some Unique Data | Unique Data
```

*I would get this*

```
         my@email.com | Some Unique Data | Unique Data

                      | Some Unique Data | Unique Data

                      | Some Unique Data | Unique Data
```

Comment: Typically this would be something you do in the app code and not the query.

Comment: No. This is generally not done in SQL. You could take the raw query results and format it this way before presenting it to the client.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should not be using SQL to perform presentational tasks. Any solution to do so is going to be very hacky and require cursors / some other iterative approach.

Almost every report authoring tool has a way to hide duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

simply you can do this --

there are so many option or answer available for this.
one of these is as follow--

```
select 
case 
when b.c_1 = 1 then 
b.col1
else
null
end col1,
b.col2 col2,
b.col3 col3
from
(
select distinct col1,col2,col3, rownum() over(partition by col1) c_1 from table_name
)b
```

now assume / modify above query -

table_name is the table name
col1 , col2  and col3 is your table's column name.

just modify this query as per your table name and structure and see..

it would be your required solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but thought this might be of use to other people. After researching this for awhile, there is a keyword called DISTINCT that will show duplicate values in a query only once.  I was using a query to auto-suggest values in a text box on a web page and didn't want it to show duplicate names and this worked for me:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT FIRSTNAME
  FROM TBLSTUDENTS
  WHERE FIRSTNAME LIKE '#ucase(arguments.search)#%'
```